# Expression: vector erase iteration outside range

Tags: c++

I need to rearrange data saved in a file and adjust the data in two other files accordingly as they data in the first file refers to the data in the second two files. This is my code and I keep getting the same error message 'vector erase iteration outside range'. (See picture) Does anyone know why I keep getting that message, I get the same message even if I remove the '+ index' in the erase function.

[image: 1]

```
std::tuple<std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>, 
    std::vector<std::string>> ordering_row() {
    
    std::fstream newfile1;
    std::fstream newfile2;
    std::fstream newfile3;
    //newfile1.open("C://Users//C21044258//source//repos//testing stuff//testing stuff//file1.txt", std::ios::in);
    //newfile2.open("C://Users//C21044258//source//repos//testing stuff//testing stuff//file2.txt", std::ios::in);
    //newfile3.open("C://Users//C21044258//source//repos//testing stuff//testing stuff//file3.txt", std::ios::in);
    newfile1.open("C://Users//C21044258//source//repos//Diagonalised matrix aquisition//Diagonalised matrix aquisition//Value.txt", std::ios::in);
    newfile2.open("C://Users//C21044258//source//repos//Diagonalised matrix aquisition//Diagonalised matrix aquisition//Columns.txt", std::ios::in);
    newfile3.open("C://Users//C21044258//source//repos//Diagonalised matrix aquisition//Diagonalised matrix aquisition//Rows.txt", std::ios::in);
    if (newfile1.is_open()) {   //checking whether the file is open
        std::string tp1;
        std::string tp2;
        std::string tp3;
        std::vector<double> col_vec;
        std::vector<double> row_vec;
        std::vector<std::string> value_vec;
        std::vector<double> col_ord;
        std::vector<double> row_ord;
        std::vector<std::string> val_ord;
        while (newfile1.good()) {   //read data from file object and put it into string.
            std::getline(newfile1, tp1);        //print the data of the string
            newfile2 >> tp2;
            newfile3 >> tp3;
            double col = std::stod(tp2);    // string to float
            double row = std::stod(tp3);
            col_vec.push_back(col);
            row_vec.push_back(row);
            value_vec.push_back(tp1);
        }
        int n = row_vec.size();
        while (n > 0) {
            double smallest = findSmallestElement(row_vec, n);
            int index = getIndex(row_vec, smallest);
            row_ord.push_back(row_vec.at(index));
            col_ord.push_back(col_vec.at(index));
            val_ord.push_back(value_vec.at(index));
            row_vec.erase(row_vec.begin() + index);
            col_vec.erase(row_vec.begin() + index);
            value_vec.erase(value_vec.begin() + index);
            n = n - 1;
            std::cout << n;
        }
        std::tuple<std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>, std::vector<std::string>> res;
        res = std::make_tuple(row_ord, col_ord, val_ord);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the value of `index`, is it always less than the size of the vector? Do you really need to erase that vector multiple times? Couldn't you just *sort* it and then traverse it?

Comment: At `col_vec.erase(row_vec.begin() + index);` you are using `row_vec.begin()` instead of `col_vec.begin()`.

Comment: Also, what do you return if the files cannot be opened?  Your function has undefined behavior, since you do not return anything when you are supposed to return a `std::tuple`.

Comment: I managed to circumvent the erase function by replacing the element at the index location of the row_vec with a huge number and that seems to at least get rid of that error message (Although the code is still not working as it should). Thank you for your help!

Comment: @BenJakobs *Although the code is still not working as it should* -- Did you address the issue I brought up, and that is your function does not return a value if the first file cannot be opened?  What if `if (newfile1.is_open())` is `false`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have not yet done that, but I will, thank you for flagging it. Any tips on how one would do that? (I'm still pretty new to c++). Also, the code now works.

Comment: @BenJakobs -- `return {};`